# Is the symmetric group $S_{\mathbb{N}}$ on countably many letters a Galois group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, permutations, galois-theory

We know $S_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the Galois group over some field $K$ (in fact also over $\mathbb{Q})$.

The construction of field $K$ and extension $L/K$ such that $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)=S_n$ requires using Artin's Theorem, which works only for finite groups.

Along similar lines, is $S_{\mathbb{N}}=\lbrace f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}\mid f\text{ bijective} \rbrace$ also a Galois group over some field?

Comment: Aren't infinite Galois groups usually required to be profinite?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Galois groups of non-algebraic extensions are not profinite, and it seems at least imaginable that the Galois group of something like a field of rational functions in infinitely many variables could be isomorphic to $S_\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, so "Galois group" just means group of automorphisms of [big] fixing [small] - there's no assumption of profiniteness? (I seem to recall getting in trouble for this at some point . . . :P) I certainly agree that it seems plausible that $S_\omega$ is the group of automorphisms of some field fixing another.